# Как спарсить значение курса из <class 'lxml.etree._Element'> с помощью zeep python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

На сайте https://cbr.ru/ есть веб-сервис выгрузки курсов валют(soap)
https://cbr.ru/DailyInfoWebServ/DailyInfo.asmx
Использую библиотеку zeep.
Все что получилось так это вытащить дочерние элементы из <Element ValuteData at 0x26924ae6f80>

```
from zeep import Client, Settings, helpers
import datetime
import json
from lxml import etree

wsdl = 'https://cbr.ru/DailyInfoWebServ/DailyInfo.asmx?WSDL'
data  = datetime.date.today()
settings = Settings(strict=False,  xml_huge_tree=True)
client = Client(wsdl, settings=settings)
xml_course = client.service.GetCursOnDateXML(data)
print(xml_course)
list_elem = xml_course.getchildren()
iter_list = []
for i in list_elem:
    print('\n')
    for j in i.getchildren():
        print(j)
```

вывод:

```
<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6740>  
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae61c0>   
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6e40>  
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6ec0>  
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6e80>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6f00>  
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6740>   
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae61c0>  
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6940>  
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6e40>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6180>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6f00>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6740>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6280>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae61c0>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6ec0>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6180>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6f00>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6e80>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6740>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6940>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6ec0>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6180>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6e40>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6f00>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6280>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6940>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6ec0>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae61c0>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6180>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6e80>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6280>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6940>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6740>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6ec0>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6e40>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6e80>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6280>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6f00>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6940>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae61c0>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6e40>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6e80>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6180>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6280>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6740>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae61c0>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6e40>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6ec0>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6e80>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6f00>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6740>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae61c0>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6940>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6e40>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6180>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6f00>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6740>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6280>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae61c0>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6ec0>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6180>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6f00>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6e80>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6740>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6940>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6ec0>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6180>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6e40>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6f00>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6280>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6940>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6ec0>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae61c0>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6180>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6e80>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6280>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6940>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6740>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6ec0>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6e40>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6e80>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6280>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6f00>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6940>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae61c0>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6e40>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6e80>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6180>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6280>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6740>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae61c0>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6e40>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6ec0>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6e80>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6f00>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6740>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae61c0>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6940>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6e40>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6180>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6f00>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6740>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6280>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae61c0>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6ec0>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6180>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6f00>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6e80>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6740>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6940>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6ec0>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6180>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6e40>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6f00>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6280>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6940>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6ec0>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae61c0>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6180>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6e80>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6280>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6940>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6740>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6ec0>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6e40>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6e80>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6280>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6f00>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6940>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae61c0>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6e40>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6e80>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6180>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6280>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6740>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae61c0>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6e40>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6ec0>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6e80>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6f00>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6740>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae61c0>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6940>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6e40>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6180>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6f00>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6740>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6280>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae61c0>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6ec0>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6180>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6f00>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6e80>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6740>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6940>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6ec0>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6180>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6e40>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6f00>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6280>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6940>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6ec0>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae61c0>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6180>


<Element Vname at 0x26924ae6e80>
<Element Vnom at 0x26924ae6280>
<Element Vcurs at 0x26924ae6940>
<Element Vcode at 0x26924ae6740>
<Element VchCode at 0x26924ae6ec0>
```

Vname — Название валюты
Vnom — Номинал
Vcurs — Курс
Vcode — ISO Цифровой код валюты
VchCode — ISO Символьный код валюты

как сделать выборку по USD и EUR и получить занчение Vcurs — Курс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем вопрос решен, просто не с тем сервисом начал работу. На сайте банка есть ресурс для работы с xml: https://cbr.ru/development/SXML/
Здесь оказалось все намного проще и быстрее

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

req = requests.get('http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp')
tree = ET.fromstring(req.content)
print(tree)
for element in tree.findall("Valute"):
    if element.attrib == {'ID':'R01235'}:
        name = element.find('Name')
        curs = element.find('Value')
        print(f'{name.text}: {curs.text}')
    if element.attrib == {'ID':'R01239'}:
        name = element.find('Name')
        curs = element.find('Value')
        print(f'{name.text}: {curs.text}')
```

Comment: Эххх, с xml любой мог бы, а вы попробуйте с WSDL :D Вчера увидел вопрос, хотел скинуть один из парсеров их сайта, но заметив, что у вас WSDL решил что будет не в тему и стало любопытно решение через WSDL :) Но +1 за то, что вы сами решили проблему ;)

Comment: эххх, вызов принят. Напишу как разберусь с WSDL))